# VBox can only be aligned vertically

Tags: java, javafx

```
VBox theBox = new VBox();
Label theLabel = new Label ();
theBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

VBox.getChildren().add(theLabel);
scene = new Scene(VBox, 1000, 1000);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Having this in my class the vbox appears but the weird thing is it only centers vertically not in the x axis.

So if I do:

`CENTER_RIGHT` it will do the first but ignore the second. So unless I wrap my VBox in a HBox, I figured I cant achieve what I want.

Is there a reason why I cant position my VBox or what am I doing wrong?

**I googled like crazy and couldnt find anything.** I even went through the entire documentation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.  The alignment does exactly what it’s supposed to do, for me.  However, I did have to make some changes to your code, as it will not compile as it is.  If you can update your question so your code is a complete, compilable program that demonstrates your problem, that would help.

Comment: Oh boy, I have an insane amount of classes. Not sure how to create something that reproduces the behaviour. Maybe it is interesting to note that my vBox is in an hBox. Either way I dont think its because of that. I have no special rules applied unless my vboxes magically expand to fill the entire screens space.

Comment: If your problem is simply that VBox isn't doing what you want, trying to isolate the problem as a separate, minimal demo may reveal the answer to you, in addition to allowing others to replicate and analyze it.  You may also want to clarify your third paragraph;  “do the first but ignore the second” is unclear (first what?  second what?), and “achieve what I want” is also unclear (what do you want to achieve?).

Comment: How is the `VBox` field/variable declared/initialized and why do you show us the `theBox` variable that seems to be irrelevant here???

Comment: @fabian You know what. I will update my answer and try to add minimal code that reflects what I currently have.